# StAX/StAX2 attributes' location in source XML

Tags: java, xml, attributes, stax, woodstox

I need to get the offsets (start and end location) in source XML for each extracted text information.

I need to use the XML PULL READING model, so I've been experimenting with StAX and StAX2 (Woodstox) for some time.

Original StAX contains API:

```
javax.xml.stream.Location
```

However, this class is rather obscure. So here goes the StAX2 (Woodstox) which contains an improved API:

```
org.codehaus.stax2.LocationInfo
```

It works nicely for elements and stuff via the LocationInfo.

My problem:
**How can I get the offset of attributes** since they are apparently a part of element? So the location's granuarity is on element level -> I can get offsets for entire element and not for each attribute...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woodstox does not track starting/ending offsets for attribute values, only for elements.

Comment: True; Actually, I was told that tracking attributes' positions is impossible due XML element/attr definition.

Comment: That is not strictly true, as the underlying scanner is in position to know the exact placement; but it does unfortunately become rather expensive due to element/attribute coupling. Ideally there would be a setting to enable such tracking, however; but Woodstox development has not been very active for past couple of years.